# How much would a solar sail's usefulness be reduced by a perforation?

Tags: propulsion, solar-sail

If one was going to use a [solar sail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sails) on a long-term space mission, it seems as though [space debris](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_debris) would be very hard to avoid.

If a solar sail was perforated by a piece of space debris, would its usefulness be greatly reduced?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  They degrade gracefully with small punctures, with the degradation approximately proportional to the area ratio of the pinholes to the total sail.  So almost not at all.

Comment: This reinforces the fact that unlike wind, light rays won't slide on the sail and rush out of the hole. Common misconception.